# Spacebar doesn't work in ckeditor 5 after using copied source code from cdn

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor 5, getting issue When copy & pasting the code from this URL https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/18.0.0/balloon/ckeditor.js into  local project the space bar (why ever) won't work - but when loading it as scrip-tag using  it'll work fine.

Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have some problem?. Can you resole this?